# Rust tell the compiler to not trust the registers?

Tags: rust, osdev, unsafe

I'm making a bootloader for x86_64 and used some compile options to bring the size of my binary down:

```ini
strip = true
opt-level = "s"
lto = true
codegen-units = 1
debug = false
overflow-checks = false
panic = "abort"
```

The problem is that when I run my bootloader, it issues a int 0x13 which changes some registers (ah=0 & carry flag is set)
I think this break the following code, because I have a print statement that causes problems, where it shouldn't

I think it's because rust assumes the registers have the right values but I'm not sure

I tried removing and re-adding the print statement:
Without it, everything works
BUT, I know the print function is supposed to work because I use it just above !
The function is:

```rust
fn write_v8(s: &[u8], offset: usize) {
    let vga_buffer = unsafe { core::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(0xb8000 as *mut u8, 80 * 25 * 2) };
    for (i, char) in s.iter().enumerate() {
        vga_buffer[i * 2 + offset] = *char as u8;
        vga_buffer[i * 2 + offset+1] = *char as u8;
    }
}
```

So this function shouldn't have any side effects...

Comment: Please provide more details. How do you invoke Rust from your bootloader? The mention of `int 0x13` indicates you are writing some assembly; how do you link the Rust code to this? Is the control flow going back and forth between assembly and Rust?

Comment: Yes, I have a very little start in asm, which then calls a rust function, which uses some assembly to int 0x13

Comment: But I think the problem comes from a u8 conversion that was wrong and was overflowing

Comment: After more testing I found something:
I get very invalid data when a variable gets bind to the register al

Comment: Which is a derived of ah, so I think I need to tell the rust compiler to not use the register

Comment: Please have a read of the [Inline assembly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html) part of the Rust Reference. In particular, there is a section on [ABI clobbers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html#abi-clobbers), which allows you to mark an `asm!` block as clobbering registers (according to the architecture). The section also describes how to mark registers as clobbered with `lateout`.